# How do I index this dataset with DateTIme?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a bit new with python and data processing elements, so sorry if this is a nooby question.

So I have a large 3D tensor(?) dataset that looks something like this:

`data = [[[a], [b]], [[c], [d]] ... ]`

And each 2D tensor in the dataset is connected to a timestamp i.e.

```
2018-09-29 05:00:00 -> [[a], [b]]
2018-09-29 06:00:00 -> [[c], [d]]
...
```

And each data-set i.e. `a, b, c, d` contains the same columns i.e:

```
a.head()
| val1 | val2 | val3 |
----------------------
|   1  |   3  |   2  |
|   3  |   5  |   6  |
|   4  |   1  |   3  |
...
```

I need to create a multivariable index, that is, a timestamp should refer to a matrix.

I've tried with:

```py
dfs = [[[a], [b]], [[c], [d]] ... ]
dates = ['2018-09-29 05:00:00', '2018-09-29 06:00:00']


x = pd.concat(dfs, keys=pd.to_datetime(dates))
```

which creates an outermost index with dates, but I have no way of reaching this index. When I list the keys with `x.keys()`, I only get the columns for a, b... i.e. `val1, val2, val3`. That is, it creates this kindof table:

```
                    | val1 | val2 | val3 |
                    ----------------------
2018-09-29 05:00:00 |   1  |   3  |   2  |
                    |   3  |   5  |   6  |
                    |   4  |   1  |   3  |
                    ----------------------
2018-09-29 06:00:00 |   1  |   3  |   2  |
                    |   3  |   5  |   6  |
                    |   4  |   1  |   3  |
```

So how do I do create this DateTime indexing of multivariate values effectively? How can I access the timestamp-keys? Are there better ways of doing this?

**Edit**

I.e how can I achieve this as shown in pandas [reshaping guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html):

```
                     a                                b                              
variable             val1      val2       val3       val1       val2         val3
date                                                                                      
2018-09-29 05:00:00  0.469112  -1.135632   0.119209  -2.104569  0.938225 -2.271265
2018-09-29 06:00:00  0.469112  -1.135632   0.119209  -2.104569  0.938225 -2.271265
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want to do, but I tried to create a little toy example,
as specified in your question. So we have 2d matrices referenced by timestamps:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    '2018-09-29 05:00:00': np.arange(9). reshape(3, 3),
    '2018-10-29 05:00:00': np.arange(9, 18). reshape(3, 3),
    '2018-11-29 05:00:00': np.arange(18, 27). reshape(3, 3)
}
```

Then I just vertically stack the data and create an index like so:

```
matrices = []
index = []

for k, v in data.items():
    matrices.append(v)
    for _ in range(v.shape[0]):
        index.append(k)
```

The dataframe would look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(matrices), index=index)
print(df)

#                       0   1   2
# 2018-09-29 05:00:00   0   1   2
# 2018-09-29 05:00:00   3   4   5
# 2018-09-29 05:00:00   6   7   8
# 2018-10-29 05:00:00   9  10  11
# 2018-10-29 05:00:00  12  13  14
# 2018-10-29 05:00:00  15  16  17
# 2018-11-29 05:00:00  18  19  20
# 2018-11-29 05:00:00  21  22  23
# 2018-11-29 05:00:00  24  25  26
```

If you want data of a specific timestamp all you have to do is use the `loc` method

```
print(df.loc['2018-09-29 05:00:00'])

#                      0  1  2
# 2018-09-29 05:00:00  0  1  2
# 2018-09-29 05:00:00  3  4  5
# 2018-09-29 05:00:00  6  7  8
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit:**

You can convert the strings to Timestamps as well `pd.Timestamp(...)` and keep on querying with strings. I'm not to knowledgable about dos and don'ts of Pandas timestamps though.

**Edit 2:**

You could save objects in t he cells instead and include the whole numpy matrix as one cell entry, but then you would loose the abillity to query single rows/column of a matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this flattens the values into multiple timestamp-indexes. Want a solution where I can access the complete 2d matrice from a timestamp. Updated the question, there is a table there that show how I want it to look like, but for some reason I'm unable to reach this outermost timestamp index

Comment: You could create a Multi index, but if you don't have any sensible values in the Multi index but just an incremented integer it amounts to the same as using iloc. As you can see searching for the datetime will give the complete Matrix just as you want. As far as I know Pandas is supposed to handle tabular data. A row without an index might not be possible, but I'm not sure.